# Obtain each value from XY graph in Simulink

Tags: simulink

how can I obtain the value from XY graph in Simulink? I just wanted to make sure I did the correct thing and obtained the correct value.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is dump the signals to MATLAB using a `To Workspace` block, and use MATLAB's visualization tools to check the data.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this =)